# how to trigger a button created on javascript using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a web application that needs to preview some report using a button inside a data table. each row on the data table has its own button created on the javascript and I want to trigger that button using the same javascript file.

Is there anyway to do this? Please see code below:

```
      $('#AccountList').append('<tr data-empid="' + row.ci_ID + '">'
        + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.ciCODe + '</td>'
        + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.FullName + '</td>'
        + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.LoanType + '</td>'
        + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.Bank + '</td>'
        + '<td  text-align:center;">' + row.Amount + '</td>'
        + '<td  text-align:center;"><label class="'+ xLabel +'"><h6>' + xText + '</h6></label></td>'            
        + '<td  text-align:center;"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary" id="btnPreview" name="btnPreview"><i class="icofont icofont-prescription"></i></button>'
        + '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-outline-danger" id="btnReinvestigate" name="btnReinvestigate"><i class="icofont icofont-redo"></i></button>'
        +'</td>'
        + '</tr>');



 $("#btnReinvestigate").click(function(){
        alert("Hello Worlds!");
     });

     $("#btnPreview").click(function(){
        alert("Hello World!");
     });
```

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending rows where elements share the same `id` is [semantically invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

In fact, you can do away with the id attribute on the buttons and instead utilise the `name` attribute.

You'll then want to [delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) your click handlers to `#AccountList`

```
$('#AccountList')
  .on('click', 'button[name="btnReinvestigate"]', function () {
    alert('Reinvestigate')
  })
  .on('click', 'button[name="btnPreview"]', function () {
    alert('Preview')
  });
```